# Number of columns equal to cell value

Tags: excel, vba

I want to make the number of columns, row 25 to 38, be equal to the number in cell C24.

If cell C24 contains 3 then I want the total number of columns to be 3.

I tried a couple of ways and adding new columns alone goes alright but removing them crashes my sheet.

```vb
Sub adding()
If LastCol = Range("C24").Value Then 
ElseIf LastCol < Range("C24").Value Then
    Range("C25:C36").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
ElseIf LastCol > Range("C24").Value Then
    Range("D25:D36").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Did you re-ask this? When you insert are you wanting to copy the C25:C36 into the newly inserted columns? And when deleting you want them deleted from D to however many columns C24 says? Also what is `LastCol`? Are you trying to get what the last used column is? If so we would also need to minus off the initial columns (ie if your last column is F, then that is column 6. But your C might only say 4 but that would be correct as it starts at column C not column A.

Comment: Kinda, I saw something went wrong with the code last time.
Column C (25 to 38) is the original column. When I fill a number in cell C24 I want an equal number of columns (this part worked well) but if I then change the number in C24 it added even more columns. Now I am trying to delete the unnecessary columns. I thought it shouldn't be so hard but I didn't manage to get it to work properly. All I could think of was to check what the last column used is
Yes I do need the correction indeed, now I just made another cell to calculate that value E.g. Cell C20:=C24+3.

Comment: The reason it was probably always inserting is because `LastCol` would always be 0 as you don't define a value for it. What do you intend with this? Check my answer below to see if that's right for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a try with the code below:

```
Sub Adding()

Dim col As Long, LastCol As Long

LastCol = Cells(25, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column - 2 'This auto finds last column using row 25.
col = Range("C24").Value

If LastCol < col Then
    Range("C25:C36").Copy
    Range("C25:C36").Resize(, Abs(LastCol - col)).Insert shift:=xlToRight
ElseIf LastCol > col Then
    Range("D25:D36").Resize(, Abs(LastCol - col)).Delete shift:=xlToLeft
Else
    'if equals do what you want
End If
Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Basically we grab the initial range (C25:C36 for inserting and D25:D26 for deleting) and use the `Resize` method to expand the range by the number of columns.
I put in the calculation for the last column but if that's not right for you then we can see what is right. Because it starts in Column C I minus 2 off the `LastCol`.

I tested it and it did what I believe you want so hopefully works for you.Let me know.

Comment: Perfect! 
I spend quite a while getting stuck with excel sheets that froze. This is exactly what I need.

Comment: No worries. Glad to help. You will notice I removed the `Select` parts of the code. This is because Select is trivial code that just slows everything down and can cause problems/errors when you're working with multiple sheets/workbooks and sometimes not even that. It probably wouldn't make a difference in this case but always best to replace it :)