# Excel creating a dynamic table of columns

Tags: excel, vba, excel-tables

I started with this solution here: [Number of columns equal to cell value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70529838/number-of-columns-equal-to-cell-value)

I want to create multiple tables down the page which will be at a fixed number of rows of 11. This inital set up that I have is in the attached image, [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FglUW.png).

I have a row in the table labelled Week which is unmerged and I want a value from Start Date to populate the first free column. I then want to take the Length in Weeks value and expand or contract the number of columns in the table to match that number and then prefill the dates in the Week row and finally fill the End Date cell.

The weeks go from Monday to Sunday, once an End Date is filled then the Start Date in the next row will fill and then wait for the user to input the Length in weeks to go through the process with a similar table down the page.

My problem at the moment is whether Excel VBA has the functionality I would need to pull this off or whether I should shift to Python and then just export an excel sheet.

I started with this solution here: [Number of columns equal to cell value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70529838/number-of-columns-equal-to-cell-value)

I got it to add the columns onto the existing one but I had issues with merged rows and it also wasn't dynamic to make the table smaller if I entered a smaller number.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: if you start with a formatted date, then you can add days to that date to get future dates. If you keep adding 7 up to the number of weeks you specify it will calculate the date of the last Sunday etc

Comment: Why don't you fill out `B3:E4` with some relevant (different) values, hide `B5:E26`, and below, show us the exact expected result?

Comment: You can definitely do what you want using VBA, but without some of your trial code to look at there's not much we can offer here.